# How to generate name combinations with initials

Tags: python

Given a string of a person's name:

```
"Richard David"
```

I'd like to create a list of all combinations of this name where up to all but one of the individual names are replaced with initials:

```
[
    "Richard David",
    "R David",
    "Richard D",
]
```

An example with three individual names:

```
"Richard Anthony David"
```

Would output:

```
[
    # replace no initials
    "Richard Anthony David",
    # replace one name with initial
    "Richard Anthony D",
    "Richard A David",
    "R Anthony David",
    # replace two names with initials
    "R A David",
    "R Anthony D",
    "Richard A D",
]
```

`itertools` is usually my go to for combinations but I can't quite work out how to build in the replacement of a name with an initial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that the order of the elements returned by [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is predictable, as guaranteed in its documentation.

```py
from itertools import product

def all_names(fullname):
    pool = [(word, word[0]) for word in fullname.split()]
    return [' '.join(name) for name in product(*pool)][:-1]

print(*all_names("Richard Anthony David"), sep='\n')
# Richard Anthony David
# Richard Anthony D
# Richard A David
# Richard A D
# R Anthony David
# R Anthony D
# R A David
```

Answer (score 2):

With the pointer on using indexes from @Barmar I came up with the following solution:

```
def create_initial_combos(name: str) -> List[str]:
    names = name.split()
    initial_names = [name]
    for i in range(len(names) - 1, 0, -1):
        for x in it.combinations(range(len(names)), i):
            names_copy = names.copy()
            for n in x:
                names_copy[n] = names_copy[n][0]
            initial_names.append(" ".join(names_copy))
    
    return initial_names
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with nested loop

```
# function with argument name & default Length_of_intitial
# So If the initial's length is 1, the Length_of_intitial is not required.

def name_combos(name, Length_of_intitial=1):

    #create a list containg words of name
    name = name.split()

    #length of list name
    L = len(name)

    #create empty list new_names
    new_names = []

    #iterate over the length of new_names
    for i in range(L):
        
        #Empty string to which the name added with
        s = ''

        #again iterate over the length of new_names
        for j in range(L):

            #Only Initials for the following conditions
            cond1 = j in range(i,  i+ Length_of_intitial)
            cond2 = i == L-1 and j==0
            
            
            if cond1 or cond2 :

                #As space is required, space is prefixed and suffixed
                s = s + ' ' + name[j][0] + ' '
            else:

                #As space is required, space is prefixed and suffixed
                s = s + ' ' + name[j] + ' '
    
        #Append derived name to the list new_names
        new_names.append(s)

    #Remove the initial space and final space of each name in the list
    for i, x in enumerate(new_names):
        new_names[i] = x[1:-1]
   
    return new_names
    
            
r = name_combos("Richard Anthony David")
print(r)
#output : ['R  Anthony  David', 'Richard  A  David', 'R  Anthony  D']

r = name_combos("Richard Anthony David", 2)
print(r)
#output : ['R  A  David', 'Richard  A  D', 'R  Anthony  D']
```